# Minimum manhattan distance with certain blocked points

Tags: algorithm, coordinate-systems

The minimum Manhattan distance between any two points in the cartesian plane is the sum of the absolute differences of the respective X and Y axis. Like, if we have two points (X,Y) and (U,V) then the distance would be: ABS(X-U) + ABS(Y-V). Now, how should I determine the minimum distance between several pairs of points moving only parallel to the coordinate axis such that certain given points need not be visited in the selected path. I need a very efficient algorithm, because the number of avoided points can range up to 10000 with same range for the number of queries. The coordinates of the points would be less than ABS(50000). I would be given the set of points to be avoided in the beginning, so I might use some offline algorithm and/or precomputation.

As an example, the Manhattan distance between (0,0) and (1,1) is 2 from either path (0,0)->(1,0)->(1,1) or (0,0)->(0,1)->(1,1). But, if we are given the condition that (1,0) and (0,1) cannot be visited, the minimum distance increases to 6. One such path would then be: (0,0)->(0,-1)->(1,-1)->(2,-1)->(2,0)->(2,1)->(1,1).

Comment: What does "certain points need not be visited in the selected path" mean?

Comment: Like if (1,0) and (0,1) need not be visited, then the Manhattan distance between (0,0) and (1,1) would no longer remain 2. Simple reason being I can't visit the the points which are necessary for the minimum path. In this case, the answer would be 6.

Comment: So you mean that those points are obstacles?

Comment: Yes! And, we obviously have to move along the coordinate points for obtaining the Manhattan distance.

Comment: Since you have a predetrmined layout, represent as an adjacency matrix. a BFS through that would be fast

Comment: No, it wont be ! BFS would depend on each coordinate on the plane, which could be 10^10 points in worst case. So, this is completely ruled out.

Comment: The 'obstacles' are part of your input. You cannot hope to find an algorithm that does not need to evaluate each of those points and still can navigate around them (worst case, that is).

Comment: But computing them using only the 'obstacle' must be sufficient. Since I know the points and they can't be more than 10^4, it must be feasible using an efficient algorithm, where an efficient algorithm can be defined upto O(10^9).

Comment: @divanshu So much about this isn't making sense. First off `O(10^9)` is `O(1)` - you're misusing that notation. Second, what you're describing ***is*** path finding. People have been suggesting standard path finding algorithms and you seem to be rejecting them. -- **What is it about your problem that makes it different than a standard path finding problem?**

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved by breadth-first search or depth-first search, with breadth-first search being the standard approach. You can also use the A* algorithm which may give better results in practice, but in theory (worst case) is no better than BFS.

This is provable because your problem reduces to solving a maze. Obviously you can have so many obstacles that the grid essentially becomes a maze. It is well known that BFS or DFS are the only way to solve mazes. See [Maze Solving Algorithms (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm) for more information.

[image]

My final recommendation: use the A* algorithm and hope for the best.

Comment: Nope. A maze is definitely a very different case. It is not related to the problem in question. My question is much simpler than solving a maze. A* would also be slow. It isn't very good asymptotically.

Comment: @divanshu You said you have a grid with obstacles, that is what a maze is.

Comment: A maze have blocked edges and not points. Here the points can go only upto O(10^4). This is the main catch. I can process each point which is an obstacle, whereas in your case it is an edge which cannot be processed in any manner. Moreover, a maze is bounded. Here, I know except the given points, all others are free. The answer is solely dependant on the given points. Much different from a maze, i guess.

Comment: That some mazes have fewer obstacles than others, or that they have bounding walls or not, it is still functionally the same problem. As I said above: A* is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

You are not understanding the solutions here or we are not understanding the problem:

1) You have a cartesian plane. Therefore, every node has exactly 4 adjacent nodes, given by x+/-1, y+/-1 (ignoring the edges)

2) Do a BFS (or DFS,A*). All you can traverse is x/y +/- 1. Prestore your 10000 obstacles and just check if the node x/y +/-1 is visitable on demand. you don't need a real graph object

If it's too slow, you said you can do an offline calculation - 10^10 only requires 1.25GB to store an indexed obstacle lookup table. leave the algorithm running?

Where am I going wrong?